# Visualizar ventanas en visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2022

**Quiero visualizar una ventana en visual studio**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
al correr el siguiente código
`introducir el código aquí`#include "ventana1.h"

```
using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
[STAThreadAttribute]
void Main(array<String^>^ args) {
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    ventana::ventana1 form;
    Application::Run(% form);
}
```

Y cuando lo corro aparece esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saben la causa, como puedo hacer que se visualize la ventana?

Gracias por el soporte colegas!

Comment: Parece que lo estas compilando como biblioteca y no como ejecutable...